# how do I access a synonym from another scheme

Tags: oracle, optimization

Any one know how to access a synonym from another scheme?
select * from abcefh.plan_table;

This doesn't work and says the table does not exist.  it is for sure there.
thanks
Saro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have select privileges on that table?

If you execute the following query, do you see any rows:

```
SELECT table_name 
  FROM all_tables 
 WHERE owner='ABCEFH' 
   AND table_name = 'PLAN_TABLE';
```

If you do not get a row returned, then you don't have privileges.

If you're saying PLAN_TABLE is a private synonym in the ABCEFH schema, then the answer is you cannot access it.

Answer (score 1):

I take it that abcefh.plan_table is a private synonym in the abcefh schema.

Can you query the table that the synonym abcefh.plan_table points to? If not, the synonym will not give you additional rights and the error message will be that the object does not exist.